# Reading from a file in java but the output skips every other line

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file and print out the results in a specific format. When it prints, it only prints every other entry. In the while loop, I tried switching the if statement around and changing 0 to -1 and then count++ but it didn't work.

```
  try
  {
     File f = new File("BaseballNames1.csv");
     FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

     ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
     String line;
     int count = 0;

     while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
     {
        if(count == 0)
        {
           count++;
           continue;
        }
        players.add(br.readLine());
     }

     for(String p : players)
     {
        String[] player = new String[7];
        player = p.split(",");

        first = player[0].trim();
        last = player[1].trim();
        birthDay = Integer.parseInt(player[2].trim());
        birthMonth = Integer.parseInt(player[3].trim());
        birthYear = Integer.parseInt(player[4].trim());
        weight = Integer.parseInt(player[5].trim());
        height = Double.parseDouble(player[6].trim());
        name = first + " " + last;
        birthday = birthMonth + "/" + birthDay + "/" + birthYear;
        System.out.println(name + "\t" + birthday + "\t" + weight + "\t" + height);
        //System.out.printf("First & Last Name %3s Birthdate %3s Weight %3s Height\n", name, birthday, weight, height);
     }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     e.getMessage();
  }
```

Comment: You are calling br.readLine() twice, before adding the line you just read. So it should be players.add(line);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is right here:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
       count++;
       continue;
    }
    players.add(br.readLine());
}
```

You're reading a new line each time, even though you already read one.  You want this:

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
       count++;
       continue;
    }
    players.add(line); //The important change is here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
players.add(br.readLine());
```

to

```
players.add(line);
```

Your version reads and writes the next line to `players`, not the current one.